# get woocommerce shop page post thumbnail

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a problem with woocommerce. I'm using the `woocommerce_before_main_content` hook to add a `.jumbotron` page cover. I was able to display the content like page title and categories that needs to appear on the background image, but the image that is displayed is the worng one, I don't know why but wordpress will show the first product image thumbnail and the image I've selected as featured inside the shop page of woocommerce is different. Is there a solution? 
I'm using this code:

```
function btheme_woocommerce_before_main_content()
  {
    if( has_post_thumbnail() ):
    ?>
      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid shop-page-cover" style="background-image:url('<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>');">
        <!-- <div class="parallax" data-parallax-image></div> -->
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h1 class=""><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
                <?php $categories = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'product_cat') ); ?>
                <?php foreach( $categories as $category ): ?>
                  <h4 class="category-name d-inline"><?php echo $category->name; ?></h4>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
      <div class="container-fluid content-wrapper" id="uptheme-woocommece-wrapper">
    <?php
  }
  add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'btheme_woocommerce_before_main_content', 10 );
```

Comment: as you said you use `woocommerce_before_main_content` action. it resets all wp queries and it runs woocommerce query.

Comment: So what's the solution to obtain what I want to achieve? I've used the hook because I'm overriding to modify the default templates and the docs suggest to use the hooks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

first you need to get post thumbnail by id

```
<?php
$shop_page_id = wc_get_page_id('shop');

function btheme_woocommerce_before_main_content()
  {
    if( has_post_thumbnail($shop_page_id) ):
    ?>
      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid shop-page-cover" style="background-image:url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($shop_page_id,'full'); ?>');">
        <!-- <div class="parallax" data-parallax-image></div> -->
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h1 class=""><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
                <?php $categories = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'product_cat') ); ?>
                <?php foreach( $categories as $category ): ?>
                  <h4 class="category-name d-inline"><?php echo $category->name; ?></h4>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
      <div class="container-fluid content-wrapper" id="uptheme-woocommece-wrapper">
    <?php
  }
  add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'btheme_woocommerce_before_main_content', 99 );
```

Comment: I will give a try, I didn't know about the `wc_get_page_id()` function. I was thinking to try using `get_page_by_path()` . Thanks for the help. Did you have a suggestion also for categories if I set a featured Image?

Comment: I think you can use `get_queried_object_id` to check for any other ids.